# What is this little board I've found in an ATX PSU?

Tags: power-supply, board

I have dissembled and old ATX power supply, and I've found this small board between the male AC input socket and the main board. What is it?

[image: ATX power supply board]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a filter.  The big round thing is a common mode choke.  It cleans up the incoming mains and prevents the high frequency noise generated by the switch-mode power supply (SMPS) from getting into the mains AC.

Comment: ... and prevents the high frequency switching noise generated by the switch-mode power supply (SMPS) from getting into mains AC.

Comment: True that.  Added, ta.

Answer (score 6):

The two blue capacitors should be Y-rated capacitors that go between mains terminals and ground (the middle wire, possibly not used here). They should be high-reliability high voltage safety-rated ceramic types.

The yellow capacitor should be an X-rated film capacitor.

The toroidal inductor is a common-mode choke which has equal turns of wire on either side of the mains so that normal-mode current cancels out (so it's like a short) but it presents a relatively high common-mode impedance to high frequencies- probably some hundreds to thousands of ohms, depending on the power supply switching frequency and what harmonic you're talking about. It does **not** look like it would pass safety standards in many countries.

The 680K resistor is to discharge the capacitors so you can't get a jolt from them.

The manufacturer may have put these parts on a separate board so they can make a low-grade supply for some countries and a more EMC-compliant supply for others.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBbcoN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: "The yellow capacitor should be an *X-rated film* capacitor." - So many images spring to mind right there...

Comment: LOL. Maybe you need to get out more.